# How can I get the existing font colour (CLI) in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I know how to change the font colour of output in Python using this (for example)

`print('\033[94m' + text)`

However, the rest of the text will then stay that colour, even after the app has closed. I could set it to a certain colour, but the user may have changed the background colour and that would be a problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('\x1b\x63')  # Esc c
```

This will reset the terminal (RIS).

Comment: Thanks. I literally just found this example as well (0 can be used to reset) `\033[0m` what is this difference between them?

Comment: Esc c resets the terminal and includes tab stops, fonts, cursor position etc. (depending on terminal capabilities), whereas Esc[0m just resets graphic attributes (colors, bold, blinking etc). So this might be better in your case.

Comment: Further, Esc[00m seems to be equivalent to Esc[0m too